# How do I refactor this JS geolocation code?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have some code that uses the JS geolocation object to find a user's current position. When the user clicks a button it populates a form field with their coordinates. They are able to do this for several locations by clicking different buttons and thus filling in different form fields. I hope that makes sense...

My code at the moment is not very dry but I can't figure out how to refactor it. The JS is:

```
var firstLocation = document.getElementById("coordinates1");
var secondLocation = document.getElementById("coordinates2");
var thirdLocation = document.getElementById("coordinates3");

// Check if Geolocation is supported, if not, show message
function getLocation1() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition1);
    } else { 
        firstLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function getLocation2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition2);
    } else { 
        secondLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function getLocation3() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition3);
    } else { 
        thirdLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
// outputs the Latitude and Longitude
function showPosition1(position) {
    firstLocation.value = position.coords.latitude + 
    ", " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showPosition2(position) {
    secondLocation.value = position.coords.latitude + 
    ", " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showPosition3(position) {
    thirdLocation.value = position.coords.latitude + 
    ", " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 instructions-wrapper">
            <p class="form-instructions">1. Add starting point coordinates </p>
            <div class="add-button" onclick="getLocation1()">+</div>
        </div> <!-- end of instructions wrapper -->
        <div class="col-xs-8 form-input">
            <%= f.input :start_point, label: false,  input_html: { id: 'coordinates1' } %>
        </div>
```

and something similar for `getLocation2` and `getLocation3`.

Comment: use arguments to the function

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an array for the `locations`, and then look up the appropriate index whenever there's a click. You should also attach the handlers properly using Javascript rather than inline attributes, which are generally considered to be pretty bad practice and lead to hard-to-manage code.

Assuming that there's an `.add-button` for each `location`, you can add a listener to each button with:

```
const locations = ["coordinates1", "coordinates2", "coordinates3"]
  .map(id => document.getElementById(id));

// in newer browsers you can forEach directly over the NodeList, but for older browsers
// you'll either need to call `Array.prototype.forEach` or use a polyfill
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.add-button'),
  (button, i) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => getLocation(i));
  }
);
```

This will call `getLocation` with the index of the clicked button (the same index as the `location` you want). Then, in `getLocation`, just retrieve the element at that index:

```
function getLocation(i) {
  const location = locations[i];
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords: { latitude, longitude }}) => {
      location.textContent = latitude + ", " + longitude;
    });
  } else { 
    location.textContent = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
```

Note that `div`s do not have meaningful `value`s, and that `innerHTML` should only be used when inserting HTML markup - use `textContent` instead.